# Retrieve a value from Terraform variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, hcl

I would like to retrieve the value of the following `pin_connection_details` and `pin_task_position` from the variable below:

How do I retrieve it?

Below is the variable from which these values need to be retrieved:

```
variable "config_settings" {
  description = "Configuration settings for the Pinpoint"
  type = list(object({
    name                           = string
    area                           = string
    version                        = string
    pin_config = object({
      pin_encrypt           = optional(bool, false)
      pin_mode              = optional(bool, false)
      pin_types = map(object({
        pin_name                    = string
        pin_port                    = string
        pin_connection_details      = optional(string, null)
        timer = object({
          start = string
          stop  = string
        })
      }))
    })
    pin_tasks = list(object({
      pin_task_name                 = string
      pin_task_position             = optional(string, null)
    }))
  }))
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Tip: to the native English speaker, your questions are rather needy. This may be why this question was downvoted (I have not voted). If you can, ask how you can solve your problem, not how others can do it for you. This exercise of personal agency would give your queries a confident air that may make them less likely to get a negative reception. (Many of your questions have been edited to encourage a tone of technical writing, and the error still keeps being made).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extended a bit your example to show how it can be achied

```
variable "config_settings" {
  description = "Configuration settings for the Pinpoint"
  type = list(object({
    name    = string
    area    = string
    version = string
    pin_config = object({
      pin_encrypt = optional(bool, false)
      pin_mode    = optional(bool, false)
      pin_types = map(object({
        pin_name               = string
        pin_port               = string
        pin_connection_details = optional(string, null)
        timer = object({
          start = string
          stop  = string
        })
      }))
    })
    pin_tasks = list(object({
      pin_task_name     = string
      pin_task_position = optional(string, null)
    }))
  }))
  default = [{
    area = "area"
    name = "name"
    pin_config = {
      pin_encrypt = false
      pin_mode    = false
      pin_types = {
        "key" = {
          pin_connection_details = "pin_connection_details"
          pin_name               = "pin_name"
          pin_port               = "pin_port"
          timer = {
            start = "start"
            stop  = "stop"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    pin_tasks = [{
      pin_task_name     = "pin_task_name"
      pin_task_position = "pin_task_position"
    }]
    version = "version"
  }]
}

output "pin_connection_details" {
  value = var.config_settings[0].pin_config.pin_types["key"].pin_connection_details
}

output "pin_task_position" {
  value = var.config_settings[0].pin_tasks[0].pin_task_position
}
```

you can play with it using 'terraform plan'

```
❯ terraform plan

Changes to Outputs:
  + pin_connection_details = "pin_connection_details"
  + pin_task_position      = "pin_task_position"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Dmytro Sirant.

The `pin_types` has 2 keys `key1` and `key2`, if I want to check the key of `pin_types` and then execute the appropriate code, how do I do that using the 

`key1 ? condition : condition`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: @xpetta if I right got your question you are looking for `for_each` https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each
In your case it will be `for_each` cycle inside which you will check condition.